# Reading Excel file with merged cells Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe, openpyxl

I have the following Excel file:

[image]

And the dataframe is

```bash
     Name  Selector  Range  Policy
0  Name 1       NaN    NaN     NaN
1     NaN       NaN    NaN     NaN
2     NaN       NaN    NaN     NaN
3     NaN       NaN    NaN     NaN
4  Name 2       NaN    NaN     NaN
```

Notice that `Name 2` is a 4-merged-row cell but I get only one row in the df.

```py
from pprint import pprint

import pandas as pd

excel_data = pd.read_excel(io="pandas.xlsx", usecols="A:D")

df = pd.DataFrame(data=excel_data)

print(df)

data = (
    df.ffill()
    .fillna(value="")
    .groupby(by=df.columns[:1].to_list(), as_index=False)
    .aggregate(func=list)
    .rename(
        columns={
            df.columns[0]: "name",
            df.columns[1]: "selector",
            df.columns[2]: "range",
            df.columns[3]: "policy",
        }
    )
    .to_dict(orient="records")
)

pprint(data)
```

When printing data in the terminal, I get the below output:

```bash
[{'name': 'Name 1',
  'policy': ['', '', '', ''],
  'range': ['', '', '', ''],
  'selector': ['', '', '', '']},
 {'name': 'Name 2', 'policy': [''], 'range': [''], 'selector': ['']}]
```

Is there any way possible to make the `data` be like below, when all columns other than the column A are empty?

```bash
[{'name': 'Name 1', 'policy': [''], 'range': [''], 'selector': ['']},
 {'name': 'Name 2', 'policy': [''], 'range': [''], 'selector': ['']}]
```

Comment: The title of the question doesn't match with what you expect. You have multiple questions in one.

Comment: Also, IMHO, your expected output doesn't make much sense. Be aware of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/1206096).

Answer (score 1):

Would this solve your problem:

```
(df[~df['name'].isna()]
.fillna('')
.to_dict(orient='records')
)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'name': 'Name 1', 'selector': '', 'range': '', 'policy': ''},
 {'name': 'Name 2', 'selector': '', 'range': '', 'policy': ''}]
```

It loses the list, but if everything else is empty it does not really matter I suppose...

Edit after a bit more thoughts.
This should do the trick:

```
(df.ffill()
.fillna("")
.groupby('name')
.agg(lambda x: list(x.unique()))
.reset_index()
.to_dict(orient='records')
)
```

Outputs:

```
[{'name': 'Name 1', 'selector': [''], 'range': [''], 'policy': ['']},
 {'name': 'Name 2', 'selector': [''], 'range': [''], 'policy': ['']}]
```

Answer (score 1):

> *Notice that Name 2 is a 4-merged-row cell but **I get only one row in the df.***

That's because pandas [trims the trailing empty rows](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/e2aa710c4abe6329be6c85689e27787868e44cdd/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py#L626) returned by [openypxl](/questions/tagged/openypxl).

As a workaround, you can make a [`DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) from the worksheet [`values`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.values) :

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

data = load_workbook("pandas.xlsx")["Sheet1"].values

header = next(data); df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=header)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

     Name Selector Range Policy
0  Name 1     None  None   None
1    None     None  None   None
2    None     None  None   None
3    None     None  None   None
4  Name 2     None  None   None
5    None     None  None   None
6    None     None  None   None
7    None     None  None   None

[8 rows x 4 columns]
```